# Why was Israel allowed to take spoil from Ai, but not Jericho?

Tags: hebrew-bible, joshua

Before Israel conquered Jericho, the Lord commanded them in Joshua 6:18–19:

> "And you, by all means abstain from the accursed things, lest you
> become accursed when you take of the accursed things, and make the
> camp of Israel a curse, and trouble it. But all the silver and gold,
> and vessels of bronze and iron, are consecrated to the Lord; they
> shall come into the treasury of the Lord.”

However, when we get to Joshua 8:2, the Lord's command is different:

> "And you shall do to Ai and its king as you did to Jericho and its
> king. Only its spoil and its cattle you shall take as booty for
> yourselves. Lay an ambush for the city behind it."

Why did the Lord not permit Israel to take any spoil for themselves when conquering Jericho, but then reversed this decision when conquering Ai?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First Fruits** There is an all-prevailing teaching throughout the Old Testament (Tanakh): *the First Fruits belong to the LORD.*! In the Torah the first of the harvest was to be taken to the Tabernacle (and later Temple) and given to the priests to dedicate to God.  In the same manner the first born of all the herds (sheep, goats, cattle, etc.) were to be separated out and dedicated to the LORD.

The "first-born" did not just apply to animals, but also to sons in the family. Instead of being sacrificed, though, they were to be redeemed with money. Thus in everything, God was to have the preeminence! He was to be recognized as the Source of all blessings.

**Jericho** So it was with Jericho: all the first things captured (the booty) were to belong to the LORD as the first fruits in the Conquest of the Promised Land.  Achan violated this principle, and was sorely punished.

The rest of the captured cities were then open for sharing all the booty, including Ai. (Once the curse was lifted.)

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at both Jericho and Ai.

**Jericho:**

Lord instructed the Israelites not to claim any spoils from the city for themselves. Why?

Jericho holds significance as the first city the Israelites took over upon entering the Promised Land. Victory was not by their own might, is was a miraculous victory. God wanted the Israelites to rely on Him for victory. It's called the Promised Land for a reason. **The prohibition against taking spoils was to show the Israelites' reliance on divine provision and to recognize God's role in their success.** Failure to adhere to this command had consequence. (Joshua 7) Achan, whose actions disobeyed God's command, consequently led to defeat for the Israelites and severe repercussions for his disobedience.

**Ai:**

Following the defeat at Ai, which occurred as a consequence of Achan's sin (referenced in Joshua 7), the Lord provided Joshua with different instructions concerning the spoils of Ai. Unlike the previous directive, the Israelites were now allowed to keep the spoils of Ai for themselves. This *adjustment* in guidance could be explained through:

1. The experience of defeat at Ai and severe punishment of Achan served as a catalyst for repentance among the Israelites, leading to the removal of the sin that had previously led to their defeat. God having tested their reliance on Him once didn't need to test them again at this point.
2. Given that Ai was not the initial conquest, the imperative to demonstrate total reliance on divine provision might have been considered less critical at this juncture.
3. It is plausible that the Lord intended for the spoils of Ai to serve as provision for the Israelites, compensating for the loss of lives and resources sustained in their unsuccessful first attempt to take the city. This would also replenish their supplies since they hadn't taken anything from Jericho.